# A different way of saying "rest of"

Tags: synonyms, academic-writing

I am writing a research paper where I want to say

> The rest of the paper is organized as follows.

in the introduction of the paper. However, the word "rest" doesn't sound good as it is perceived as if I am explaining about an unimportant part of the paper. I checked some synonyms on Grammarly, but nothing really fits well.

I thought about the following:

> The remaining paper

It also sounds odd as it sounds like "leftover" to me. I can be wrong as well.

> The remnant of the paper

This is used mostly for historical events as far as I know.

Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/146741/discussion-on-question-by-cfourpio-a-different-way-of-saying-rest-of); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 29):

I suggest you use [***remainder***](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/remainder). The Cambridge English dictionary gives the following definition and usage examples (among others):

> the part of something that is left after the other parts have gone, been used, or been taken away
>
> The *remainder* of the paper is organized as follows.
>
> The *remainder* of this paper is structured as follows.
>
> The *remainder* of the paper is structured as follows.
>
> We shall use this notation in the *remainder* of the paper.
>
> The *remainder* of this paper attempts to sketch the outline of such an approach.
>
> The *remainder* of this paper is a contribution to the development of such an understanding.

Answer (score 10):

Your idea that *remnant* is used in a historical context is mistaken.

You say that *rest* suggests unimportant leftovers - actually I would suggest that *remnant* has that sense. You can use *rest* or *remainder* to mean 'the parts I haven't already described'.

Comment: In my many years in academia, I don't think I have ever seen the phrase "the remnant of the paper".

Comment: @Kimball to me it implies a leftover fragment after the paper has been destroyed.

Answer (score 8):

You could refer to the first part as *introduction* and instead of saying "the rest of the paper" you can use ***the main body of the paper.***

[University of Hull](https://libguides.hull.ac.uk/essays/main#:%7E:text=The%20main%20body%20of%20your,the%20inevitability%20of%20your%20conclusion.) explains:

> The ***main body*** of your essay is where you deliver your argument. Its building blocks are well structured, academic paragraphs. Each paragraph is in itself an individual argument and when put together they should form a clear narrative that leads the reader to the inevitability of your conclusion.

Comment: This may work, but there can be several parts of a research paper which are neither part of the introduction nor the main body of the paper - one could argue the conclusion, figures, tables, bibliography, and supplementary material are not the "main body". In general, I don't see "main body" and "everything but the introduction" as perfectly synonymous.

Comment: I like both "subsequent," and "balance," a lot, but I prefer this answer. Name the part of the paper you want to refer to, "body" or "main body" or an alternate approach would be refer to the whole paper and include the intro in your explanation of the structure.

Answer (score 6):

You could also say, "The balance of the paper ...."

Merriam-Webster [has an example:](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/balance)

> 4c: something left over : remainder
>
> answers will be given in the balance of this chapter—
> R. W. Murray

Answer (score 2):

This is mentioned in some comments, but not any answers so far:

It is perfectly fine to simply say: "The paper is organized as follows."  You can also just jump in and say: "In Section 1, we ..." and continue like that.

You can also say "the remainder of the paper", but to my ears this is a little bit weirder than just saying "The paper is organized..." because typically the introduction is a small part of the paper.

Source: I have been in academia (mathematics, if it matters) for many years, and both read and written many research papers.

Pro-tip: If you're not sure how to write something, try looking at some other papers in you field.

Answer (score 1):

"the next parts of the paper" (if it is just after) or "the later parts of the paper" (if it comes a bit farther).

Maybe also "subsequent".

See also [www.thesaurus.com](http://www.thesaurus.com)

Answer (score 1):

'The paper continues …' is brief and flexible enough connective to be used to introduce most any content.